# Expectation w.r.t. Haar measure of $R\cdot\text{diag}(R^\top \Sigma R) \cdot R^\top$

Tags: probability, rotations, haar-measure

Let $\Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a positive definite matrix and $\mu$ be the Haar measure over all orthogonal matrices $\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. 
What is
$$\mathbb{E}_{R \sim \mu} \left[R\cdot\textrm{diag}(R^\top \Sigma R) \cdot R^\top\right]?$$

Comment: It is easy to show that the eigenvectors of $\Sigma$ and $\mathbb{E}_{R \sim \mu} \left[R\cdot\textrm{diag}(R^\top \Sigma R) \cdot R^\top\right]$ are the same and the sum of the eigenvalues of both matrices must also be the same.

Comment: I found the solution: For the i'th eigenvalue $\tilde{\lambda}_i$ of $\mathbb{E}_{R \sim \mu} \left[R\cdot\textrm{diag}(R^\top \Sigma R) \cdot R^\top\right]$ it holds that $\tilde{\lambda}_i = \bar{\lambda} + \frac{2(\lambda_i - \bar{\lambda})}{2+n}$ where $\lambda_i$ is the i'th eigenvalue of $\Sigma$ and $\bar{\lambda} = \frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{i=1}\lambda_i.$